# Accessibility Inspector doesn't work on iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, accessibility-inspector, ios11.2

it seems the accessibility inspector is not working well with iOS 11.2. Is there a known workaround or maybe apple introduced a new switch?

Thanks!

**iOS 11.2** 
[image: iOS 11.2]

**iOS 11.0.1** is working correctly
[image: iOS 11.0.1]

Answer (score 1):

Luckily this fixes the issue

```
Simulator > Hardware > Erase all contents and settings
```

[image]